# MapXtreme Java Edition

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, java, mapxtreme

I'm learning GIS in Java with MapXtreme Java Edition but I can't find MapXtreme Java Edition file setup for Window (trial).

Can you share link download or software for me?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate where you have looked and whether or not you have contacted the software developers, please?

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo MapXtreme Java has been "replaced" by our new server offering; Spectrum Spatial

Here is a [link to a document](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/spectrum/lim/8_0/pdf/SpectrumSpatial_Migration_Guide.pdf) describing the path forward from MapXtreme Java and Envinsa to Spectrum Spatial.

Spectrum spatial is a bundling of a number of modules in the Pitney Bowes Spectrum Technology Platform, for example the Location Intelligence Module and the Enterprise Routing Module and some others.